# Won't write output to logfile on Unix/Linux but does on Windows

Tags: python

I have the following code, it will create the logfile on both platforms, but it will only write the output to the windows logfile.

```
import os                       

logdir = os.getenv("logs")                          
logfile = 'script_list.log'
path = (raw_input("Enter dir: "))                                   
if os.name == "posix":
    log = open("//".join([logdir,logfile]), 'w')                        
else:
    log = open("\\".join([logdir,logfile]), 'w')                        
for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(path):           
    for filename in [f for f in filenames]: 
        if os.name == "posix":
            log.write(str(dirpath)+ "//" + str(filename) + "\n")    
        else:
            log.write(str(dirpath)+ "\\" + str(filename) + "\n")    
print '\nYour logfile ' + logdir + '\\' + logfile + ' has been created'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `//` instead of `/`? Only `\\ ` needs to be escaped, "//" actually means two "/".

Comment: Maybe the `logging` module is helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you replace

```
if os.name == "posix":
    log = open("//".join([logdir,logfile]), 'w')                      
else :
    log = open("\\".join([logdir,logfile]), 'w')
...
    for filename in [f for f in filenames]:
        if os.name == "posix":
            log.write(str(dirpath)+ "//" + str(filename) + "\n")    
        else:
            log.write(str(dirpath)+ "\\" + str(filename) + "\n")
```

with

```
log=open(os.path.join(logdir, logfile), 'w')
...
    for filename in filenames:
        log.write(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)+'\n')
```

Or even better, use

```
logfilename=os.path.join(logdir, logfile)
log=open(logfilename, 'w')

...

print "Your logfile", logfilename, "has been created."
```

As [@Lycha says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9484013/589206), it's a good idea to close your file again. So your construct would be

```
with open(logfilename, 'w') as log:
    ...
```

Comment: Perfect, this sorted it I used the second suggestion.  Works like a dream.  Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the stream after writing:

```
log.flush()
```

You should also close the file in the end (preferrably using try-finally clause).